# Alex lex.x compilation : Not in scope 'begin'

Tags: haskell, alex

I have the below statements in Lex.x to parse block comments.

```
<0>  "//".*                 { tokWValue LTokComment   }            
<0>  "/*"                   { begin blockcomment      }            
<blockcomment> "*/"         { begin 0                 }            
<blockcomment> .            { tokWValue LTokComment   }
```

But If I generate Lex.hs using Alex, it does not add the 'begin' function.
This results in the below compilation error.

```
src/Lex.x:367:18: Not in scope: ‘begin’
src/Lex.x:368:18: Not in scope: ‘begin’
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

I am using wrapper 'posn'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start codes are only available when using any of the `monad-...` wrappers.

If you read the docs for the monad wrapper -- [Section 5.3.3 - The "monad" wrapper](https://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/wrappers.html) -- you see that it is the first wrapper which keeps track of the start code.

You can also verify this by finding the alex wrapper files -- look for the directory containing the files `AlexWrapper-basic`, `AlexWrapper-posn`, etc. On OS X when installing the Haskell Platform they are located in a directory like `/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/share/alex-3.1.4`. The functions `begin` and `andBegin` only occur in the monad-related wrappers.

Comment: The Alex documentation does not mention any dependence on the wrappers. [alex documentation](https://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/alex-files.html). Anyways thanks for your reply!